# How to dynamically resize text fields in Adobe Acrobat using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox to populate an existing Adobe Acrobat PDF template.
In this template I have fixed sizes of text fields in which I insert data from database.

In one text field the amount of data may vary so it would be great if text field could get bigger or smaller to adjust to the amount of text inserted.

The main problem is that I have another text fields below the one I want to resize dynamically so in case of making it bigger or smaller other text fields have to move relatively

I was searching for the solution but found only offers to resize font dynamically, but it doesn't satisfy my needs. I could create one text field and insert all of my data in it, but some of those text fields must have different color of text so it's important to have different text fields to be able to specify their color in code (as far as I know).

Is that even possible and if not what can I do to achieve the result I'm looking for?

P.S. Our code is based on templates from Adobe Acrobat and Apache PDFBox, so it's more preferable to keep it that way. But if this is not possible with those two, I will be glad to hear your recommendations on what should I use (open source first).

PDF Producer: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (32-bit) 21.7.20102,
PDF Version: 1.6 (Acrobat 7.x),
Apache PDFBox Version: 2.0.26

You can find an example of my PDF below

[image]

Comment: You could adjust the rectangle of the field widget

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Сan you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Something like `acroForm.getField(name).getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle()` / `setRectangle`. However it's a bad idea to change existing forms that are not your own, because if they get printed and then scanned and processed the forms software that companies use assumes that you didn't adjust the form.

Comment: Concerning your wish to move the fields below the resized field up or down accordingly - you'll also have to adapt their rectangles. And if you actually have not only the fields but also static text to move, things get really complicated.